# Python pandas dataframe aggregation output

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like like this:

```
Sr.No   Value1  Value2  Value3  Type
    1   2       1        N      A
    2   3       1        M      A
    3   3       2        X      A
    4   0       1        Y      B
    5   10      2        Z      B
    6   3       4        J      A
    7   5       6        K      A
```

How can i generate the output like this using Pandas Python.

```
Sr.No   Value1  Value2  Value3     Type
1       8       4       N,M,X       A
2       10      3       X,Y         B
3       8       10      Z,J,K       A
```

Basically i am looking for doing grouping based on consecutive value1, value 2 sum and type. 
How can i achieve this?

I have attempted it with this code, but it is not returning the required output.

```
grpbook = pandabook.groupby(['Value1','Value2','Type']).agg({'Value1': 'sum','Value2': 'sum', 'Value3': lambda ind: ','.join(ind) })
```

The Type Value **A** is divided into two groups based on index and sequence.

Comment: Okay, i will add my code as well.

Comment: I have edited, and added the code that i am currently doing.

Comment: A is broken down into 2 groups. Is this due to the row index grouping?

Comment: yes, this is based on sequence/index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with `cumsum` to generate pseudo *group-id*:

```
df["group_id"] = (df.Type != df.Type.shift()).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
```

And use it to divide df into groups:

```
df = df.groupby(["group_id", "Type"]).sum().reset_index().drop("group_id", 1)
df["Sr.No"] = df.index+1
print(df)
  Type  Sr.No  Value1  Value2
0    A      1       8       4
1    B      2      10       3
2    A      3       8      10
```

Comment: Excellent Chris (+1) Instead of `cumsum` I was onto finding boundary. BTW, this one is relatively better than forming boundary.

Comment: Chris, i have changed a qustion a bit, because you current solution with sum() won't work for me. Please check the question.

Comment: Okay, I'm interested to know if there's a more efficient solution to the *updated* problem too. Only way I can think of is to loop through the rows in the frame explicitly. @Chris' answer definitely works well on your original question though.

Comment: @meW Always nice to be praised :) Thanks!

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar Glad to help :)

Comment: There is another quick help regarding this needs. What if i have to generated group id based on multiple column. e.g. if i have type and type2

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar Why not `zip` type and type2 and then make group_ids on zipped tuples? I'll be glad to help further in additional question or, preferably, in discussion chat, as SO doesn't really encourage long-list of comments.